# Expo development build: No bundle url present

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, eas, expo-build

I have an expo-managed app with native packages that runs fine on my simulator with `npx expo run:ios`. I can also run it on my physical device with `npx expo run:ios --device`

However, when I try to use `eas build --profile development --platform ios`, although the build is finished successfully, upon scanning the QR code with my iPhone, I get this error:

```
No bundle URL present.

Make sure you're running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle.
```

[image]

My `eas.json`:

```json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.17.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
      },
      "env": {
        "BE_BASE_URL": "https://api.sotravel.me"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "env": {
        "BE_BASE_URL": "https://api.sotravel.me"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually fixed this by adding `"distribution": "internal",` to my `eas.json` after seeing [this page](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/) on the Expo docs:

```json
{
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

With this option set to true, the EAS CLI then prompted me to install `expo-dev-client`. Although it's equivalent to the fields:

```
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
      },
```

... those didn't prompt me to install `expo-dev-client`, which was apparently necessary to run the development build. And those were the auto-generated configs from `eas build:configure`. Hm....